# ModuleNotFoundError in python even with file __init__.py and sys.path.append

Tags: python

I am trying to create a distributable python package and below is the folder structure of my project.

[image]

When I run the file under the folder `examples` with `import ultralight as ul`, I always get the error notifying that module `ultralight` could not be found. I have tried using `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '..', 'ultralight'))` but it still not works. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Did you `sys.path.append` before or after `import ultralight` ?

Comment: I used it before `import ultralight`

Comment: If you install the `ultralight` package in a virtual environment first, you don't need to make your code adapt to the directory hierarchy imposed by your repository. Your *scripts* should almost never need to mess with `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Remove `'ultralight'` from the `os.path.join`

With `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '..', 'ultralight'))` you are adding a path that is *inside* the ultralight folder.

With `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '..'))`, you are adding a path that *contains* the ultralight folder in it.

It's lucky you didn't also have a self-similarly named file `ultralight/ultralight.py`, a common pattern to have, or your import would have been importing that file and not highlighting that the path to the module wasn't correct.

Comment: You are correct. Following up questions: how could I access the class `Trainer` in module `aa_trainer.py`?

Comment: `from ultralight import aa_trainer` will make `aa_trainer.Trainer` accessible.

`from ultralight.aa_trainer import Trainer` will make `Trainer` accessible.

If your `ultralight/__init__.py` has something that exposes the `Trainer` class, like `from .aa_trainer import Trainer`, then `import ultralight` will make `ultralight.Trainer` accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your module file is one level above your script file, so you can try something like:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..')) #  set path to parent directory
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../ultralight')) #  set path to modules
import ultralight as ul
```

Please let me know if it works.